# How to find $[T]_\beta ^\beta$ for $\beta$ based on the following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $\alpha=\{(1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,0)\}$ be a basis for $R^3$. Let $T$ satisfy $T((1,1,1))=(2,2,2), T((1,1,0))=(3,3,0)$ and $T((1,0,0))=(-1,0,0)$. How to find $[T]_\beta ^\beta$ for $\beta$ the standard basis for $R^3$?

So I think, by change of basis, $[T]_\beta ^\beta$ can be written as $[T]_\beta ^\beta$ = $[I]_\alpha^\beta$ $[T]_\alpha ^\alpha$ $[I]_\beta^\alpha$ =$[I]_\alpha^\beta$ $[T]_\alpha ^\alpha$ $([I]_\alpha^\beta )^{-1}$

The problem here I don't know how to locate $[I]_\alpha^\beta$ and $[T]_\alpha ^\alpha$.

Could someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align*}
v_1 &= \langle1,1,1\rangle & v_2 &= \langle 1,1,0\rangle & v_3 &=\langle 1,0,0\rangle
\end{align*}
so $\alpha=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. Then note that
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrccrcrcrc}
T(v_1) & = & \langle 2,2,2\rangle & = & \color{purple}{2}\, v_1 &+& \color{blue}{0}\,v_2 &+& \color{red}{0}\,v_3 \\
T(v_2) & = & \langle 3,3,0\rangle & = & \color{purple}{0}\, v_1 &+& \color{blue}{3}\,v_2 &+& \color{red}{0}\,v_3 \\
T(v_3) & = & \langle -1,0,0\rangle & = & \color{purple}{0}\, v_1 &+& \color{blue}{0}\,v_2 &+& (\color{red}{-1})\,v_3 
\end{array}
This implies that
$$
[T]_\alpha^\alpha=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\color{purple}{2} & \color{purple}{0} & \color{purple}{0} \\
\color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{0} \\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, the matrix $[I]_\alpha^\beta$ is obtained by inserting the vectors in $\alpha$ into columns
$$
[I]_\alpha^\beta=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Finally, your formula becomes
\begin{align*}
[T]_\beta^\beta
&= [I]_\alpha^\beta[T]_\alpha^\alpha[I]_\beta^\alpha \\
&= 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
&=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 4 & -1 \\
0 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}